# What's the purpose of the AppDelegate and ViewController files that Xcode generates?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have written a few functioning iPhone applications, but mostly by following tutorials that tell you where to write the code. As a result I have gone without understanding what these files are actually designed to hold.

I made an app with code that is in the `application` method of the `AppDeleagte` file, so it gets called when the program runs. I wanted to make this code run on a button press instead, so I added a button, but when I came to put the code in the relevant `IBAction`, I realised all the variables and methods i needed were in the `AppDelegate` file, so I couldn't use them in the `ViewController` file.

So my immediate question is "how should I organise my code so that I can have it run on a button press?", but an explanation of the concepts behind it would be great too, becuase then I can do it without asking next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the AppDelegate deals with application level events. Example: application becomes inactive, application starts etc. So whatever you need to setup when the application starts can go in there. As for your problem, I would suggest moving the variables to perhaps a singleton class or have another class that just contains variables and methods as a member in your appdelegate and do like madhu suggests. Having variables and methods directly in your app delegate works, but it can become big and nasty after a while.

Comment: Alright, so there should just be one appDelegate file doing the application management, then the code I write should be sorted in to class files which get imported to the viewController if they need to be tied to a UI element?

Comment: Yeah. I mean there are lots of ways to do it, but try to keep the appdelegate small and only have app event relative code there. You can have singletons handling data that is used through the app or similar.

Answer (score 1):

## import "AppDelegate"

in implementation file of viewcontroller

```
AppDelegate *app=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

[app inappDelegateDeclaredFunctionname];
```

Comment: Do I need to declare it in the header file too?

Comment: No.if u want any instant help then keep login in iphone / ipad chat room with desktop notification